# Split string with Regex on variable pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm going crazy over a fairly simple problem: I have a list of list that i want to split. There's a fairly easy pattern, but with a variation that I can't seem to capture:

```
 [['XXOOY00 100.00–200.00 300.000 -1.000 XX0IY00 300.00–400.00 500.000 +10.000 XX2IY00 600.00–700.00 800.00 0.000'],
['XXOOY00 100.00–200.00 300.000 -1.000 XX0IY00 300.00–400.00 500.000 XX2IY00 600.00–700.00 800.00 0.000']]
```

The general pattern in the list éléments is code, range, value, change. As you can see there's a variation in the pattern in the second list, because the second element only had code,range, value. In order to split these lists, I use this regex:

```
for element in list:
    final_list.append(re.split('([A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{1}[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{2}\s\S*\s\S*\s\S*)\s', element))
```

However, this fails on the second list because I have:

```
[['XXOOY00 100.00–200.00 300.000 -1.000, XX0IY00 300.00–400.00 500.000 +10.000, XX2IY00 600.00–700.00 800.00 0.000'],
['XXOOY00 100.00–200.00 300.000 -1.000, XX0IY00 300.00–400.00 500.000 XX2IY00, 600.00–700.00 800.00 0.000']]
```

While the expected result is:

```
[['XXOOY00 100.00–200.00 300.000 -1.000, XX0IY00 300.00–400.00 500.000 +10.000, XX2IY00 600.00–700.00 800.00 0.000'],
    ['XXOOY00 100.00–200.00 300.000 -1.000, XX0IY00 300.00–400.00 500.000, XX2IY00 600.00–700.00 800.00 0.000']]
```

Which regex patter would allow me to do this?

To clarify: I want a list so that if I read the content of the list element wise I have:

```
XXOOY00 100.00–200.00 300.000 -1.000
XX0IY00 300.00–400.00 500.000 +10.000
XX2IY00 600.00–700.00 800.00 0.000
XXOOY00 100.00–200.00 300.000 -1.000
XX0IY00 300.00–400.00 500.000
XX2IY00 600.00–700.00 800.00 0.000
```

Thank you.

Comment: In your list, `"+10.000"` appears in the first sublist, however, it is removed in your desired output. Is that a typo, or should values similar be removed during the split?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're looking for but what about `[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9][A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{2}[^A-Z]*`?

Comment: Ajax, fixed that, it was a typo sorry! Ctwheels, I'll try it in half an hour, I'll let you know.

Comment: Ctwheels, your pattern returns me a list of empty lists :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the fact that your optional 'change' field is built of digits, +, - and decimal point, wich can be expressed in a re pattern as: `\s[0-9\+\-\.]+` (include the preceding space is convenient)

Now you want one or zero occurences of this pattern: `(\s[0-9\+\-\.]+)?`

This needs grouping (parentheses) but you don not want that group captured and added separately in your resulting list. So you must make it a *non-capturing* group: `(?:\s[0-9\+\-\.]+)?`

A complete pattern could be:

`'([A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9][A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{2}\s\S+\s\S+(?:\s[0-9\+\-\.]+)?)'`

Comment: This could work! I'll let you know as soon as I try it on the real DB tomorrow! Thanks

Comment: Works good! Thank you. Generally a different pow on things can help...didn't think about non-capturing group on the change field.